# python - unable to connect to TLS1.2 enabled HiveServer2

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, sqlalchemy, impyla

I have HiveServer2 with SSL (minimum TLS1.2 enabled only) and LDAP enabled, no kerberos enabled. hive.server2.transport.mode = binary.
Beeline connections work fine like:
 `beeline -u jdbc:hive2://domain:10000/default\;ssl=true\;sslTrustStore=/home/user/query.jks\;trustStorePassword=blah -n user -p pass -e "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 3"`

As expected, via beeline not passing the right truststore details or wrong ldap credentials means connection does not work.

I want to use a python library to connect to HiveServer2 (specifically this Hive setup with TLS1.2).

I have looked at several libraries like impyla, pyhive, pyhs2, sqlalchemy but none are working for me.
I see several issues raised by others:

- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-SQL-Apache-Hive/Impyla-TLS-SSL-issues-with-newer-versions-of-SSL/td-p/65136
- https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/293
- https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/203
- https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/240
- https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/143

There are many examples online of connecting without a TLS1.2 protected HiveServer2 instance.

`>>> from impala.dbapi import connect

> > > conn = connect(host='domain', port=10000, use_ssl=True, auth_mechanism='LDAP', user='user', password='pass', ca_cert='/home/user/query.pem')
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/dbapi.py", line 147, in connect
> > >           auth_mechanism=auth_mechanism)
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py", line 658, in connect
> > >           transport.open()
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/**init**.py", line 68, in open
> > >           self._trans.open()
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.py", line 118, in open
> > >           message=message)
> > >       thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to domain:10000: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:726)`

Comment: Any update on if you got something to work?

Comment: jaydebeapi or pyodbc neither is really native

Comment: Hi any updates until now, i am also stuck in this issue.

Comment: nah, switched to presto. hive is dead

Answer (score 1):

If HiveServer2 runs with SSL enabled, impyla (0.13.8+) works well. If HiveServer2 runs with SSL disabled, pyhive works well.

For more details on dependencies, installation, and examples, see this page:

https://mr3docs.datamonad.com/docs/k8s/user/access-python/